# Error con MySQL conector JDBC 8 - JAVA

Tags: java, jsp

Estoy usando el conector de mysql JDBC 8 y me dio un primer error donde me decía:

> Cargando la clase `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver '. Esto está en desuso. La nueva clase de controlador es` com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Ya la cambié como me dice pero ahora me da otro error que es el siguiente:

> Error de conexión: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Mi conexion está de la siguiente manera y mi servidor es payara server

```
public Connection getConexion() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ventas?user=root&password=");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error de conexion: " + e);
            Logger.getLogger(CConexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando esta linea para la conexión;

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/ventas?user=root&password=?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Por default mysql usa el puerto 3306, si no lo especificas posiblemente también te tire alguna excepción.

Otra opción sería configurar en MySQl con la opción set global;

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = inserta aqui tu zona;
```